# PHP equivalent to Perl format function

Tags: perl, format

Is there an equivalent to Perl's format function in PHP? I have a client that has an old-ass okidata dotmatrix printer, and need a good way to format receipts and bills with this arcane beast.

I remember easily doing this in perl with something like:

```
format BILLFORMAT = 
Name: @>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    Age: @###
      $name,                          $age
.
write;
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated, banging my head on the wall with this one. O.o

UPDATE: I cannot install Perl in this environment, otherwise I would simply use Perl's format function directly.

Comment: Are you trying to fit fields on pre-printed forms?

Comment: Yes, sinan, indeed i am. :( Not happy about it, mind you, heheh, but yes.

Comment: OK, my answer does not help then. Good luck!

Comment: I believe I have my answer, there isn't a PHP equivalent. printf can be used to simulate a lot of the alignment functionality, but is still missing quite a bit of the amazing functionality that Perl format has. I'll give this one to Joshua as his solution did come the closest to a solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use printf to do something similar.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

```
printf("Name: %21s     Age: %3i\n",$name,$age);
```

If you wanted the name left aligned, you would just add a -

```
printf("Name: %-21s     Age: %3i\n",$name,$age);
```

It defaults to right aligned.

Comment: That's great for simply replacing variables, but it does not allow the flexibility for aligning rows and iterating through arrays such as the perl format function does. ;-)

Comment: While it is quite different from perl's format function it does allow for alignment and iteration (quite easily).  printf was born to do what he's talking about doing: formatting output for fixed width devices.

Comment: I will do more research in to printf to see if there's anything it is missing from the format function then, thanks Joshua.

Comment: But `format` can do so much more. There's `format xyz_TOP`. There's the ability to apply the format to a stream somewhere, then prepare the data elsewhere and simply `write`. Run code in the format. Cut off (and reuse) data that's too long for a field and so on and on... There's a lot to code when trying to replace it by printf.

Comment: Agreed, volkerK, that's what I need to look into as far as what I need for this instance. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a Perl process to control the printer, you could serialize the data in PHP and pass it to a Perl script.

I've had great luck using [PHP::Serialization](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP::Serialization) to handle data serialization and sharing between Perl and PHP.  You could also use YAML or JSON for this task.

Comment: If I could use perl, I would just use the Perl format and read the data I need directly from the database though. Sorry, I should have stated that up front, I guess.

Comment: @Dustin, I figured there was a good chance it wouldn't work out since you asked for a PHP solution.  My response may fit someone else's needs.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a perfect situation to use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
const DB = [
  'Anne Brown'     => [51, '2417 Joseph Pike, Branchstad, MS 71701'],
  'Heather Hoover' => [53, '161 Smith Inlet Medinabury, WA 63029'],
  'Mario Keith'    => [36, '303 Mcgrath Grove, Hunterberg, MH 80228'],
];

/* assuming you are trying to replicate
Name: @>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    Age: @###
      $name,                          $age
  Address: @*
           $address

.
*/
const format = <<<EOF
Name: %23s    Age: %4d
  Address: %s


EOF;

foreach (DB as $name => $details) {
  printf(format, $name, $details[0], $details[1]);
}
```

Comment: Heredoc also falls quite short of the format functionality. Again, lacks array iteration, vertical and horizontal alignment, etc.

Comment: I was unaware that `format` provided iteration. The vertical alignment could easily be accomplished with the `str_pad` function. Based on feedback, it looks like `printf` is your best bet anyway.

Comment: Ouch, I'm picking up some hate here.